# Suppress the Console Window when building an application with MATLAB Compiler

Tags: matlab, console-application, show-hide

I don't have the [MATLAB Builder™ NE](http://www.mathworks.fr/products/netbuilder/), and I need to plot some complicated graphs using values I get from a C# application.

So I used the build tool within MATLAB Compiler to build a Console Application, then I start it as a process from my C# Application and pass the parameters to it.

Everything is working fine, I'm just bothered by the black application screen that shows in the beginning. **I wish I could hide the console application window at startup** (like when you use `this.Hide();` in C# or `@echo off` in Batch files.

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to tell the deployment tool that you want to create a Windows Standalone Application, rather than a Console Application.

Comment: Im trying to find the diffrence between the two and how this can be useful to me ?! can you help ?

Comment: The difference is that Console Application shows a console window, and Windows Standalone Application does not, which is what you asked for. Roughly, Console Application is intended for when you have a command-line application that is launched from a console, whereas Windows Standalone Application is intended for applications with some sort of GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use mcc with -e switch to suppress the console window.